# Is there a way to only have carrierwave run when certain attributes are added?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I have a song model that has genre taggings using [acts-as-taggable-on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) and it is very slow and causing timeouts on saving/updating. Without tags, I can save a record in about 2 seconds, but with tags its averaging around 17 seconds. The problem I have is when is when creating a song, I am also uploading a music file and am using carrierwave to process and encode/add tags to the file itself so this has to all be done at once.

Right now my idea is to create the song record, and move all tag saving to a delayed job, and then have carrierwave do its thing. So far I'm not seeing anything in the docs that would allow me to. My other option is to have carrierwave process the file twice using `recreate_versions!` but I'd like to avoid having to do that if possible.

Comment: Why does tagging one song take soo long? How many tags do you add to a song? Is the database missing some indexes?

Comment: @spickermann don't indexes result in slower inserts? currently I don't have those columns indexed and I would say on average about 5-10 tags

Comment: @spickermann actually the taggings table is indexed

Comment: When the `act-as-taggable-on` first checks if a tag already exists then an index would improve the check a lot. It really depends on the implementation details of that gem. But spending 15 seconds just to add 5-10 tags to one song sounds ridiculous. I would investigate and fix that first.

Comment: @spickermann so just the taggings table should be indexed or also the field that I call `acts_as_taggable_on :column` ?

Comment: I do not know. That is something that you need to investigate. Look into your log files to find out what query consume so much time. Then analyze what the queries are doing and play around with indexes. But for me - without knowing your database schema and being able to look into the logs - it is impossible to tell. But something is wrong.